# Marey diagram in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to produce a Marey Diagram (similar to the first chart in [this visualization](https://mbtaviz.github.io/)). It should show trains as distinct lines, with station names on the Y axis and time of arrival on the X axis.

Here is a snip of my dataframe:

| stop_name | stop_id | trip_id | arrival_time | departure_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lindenwold | 1 | 5976 | 0 | 0 |
| Ashland | 2 | 5976 | 120 | 120 |
| Woodcrest | 3 | 5976 | 180 | 180 |
| Haddonfield | 4 | 5976 | 360 | 360 |
| Westmont | 5 | 5976 | 480 | 480 |
| Collingswood | 6 | 5976 | 600 | 600 |
| Ferry Avenue | 7 | 5976 | 720 | 720 |
| Broadway | 8 | 5976 | 960 | 960 |
| City Hall | 9 | 5976 | 1080 | 1080 |
| 8th and Market | 10 | 5976 | 1380 | 1380 |
| 12-13th and Locust | 12 | 5976 | 1560 | 1560 |
| 15-16th and Locust | 13 | 5976 | 1620 | 1620 |
| Lindenwold | 1 | 5977 | 2700 | 2700 |
| Ashland | 2 | 5977 | 2820 | 2820 |
| Woodcrest | 3 | 5977 | 2880 | 2880 |
| Haddonfield | 4 | 5977 | 3060 | 3060 |
| Westmont | 5 | 5977 | 3180 | 3180 |
| Collingswood | 6 | 5977 | 3300 | 3300 |
| Ferry Avenue | 7 | 5977 | 3420 | 3420 |
| Broadway | 8 | 5977 | 3660 | 3660 |
| City Hall | 9 | 5977 | 3780 | 3780 |
| 8th and Market | 10 | 5977 | 4080 | 4080 |
| 12-13th and Locust | 12 | 5977 | 4260 | 4260 |
| 15-16th and Locust | 13 | 5977 | 4320 | 4320 |

You can see that the trip_id column represents distinct trains stopping at 13 stations along the track.

My issue is that I use the code below to plot the graph, and the axes are correct (i.e. what I expect, but the trips are not drawing as individual lines, nor are they moving from left to right as intended.

```
x = df4['arrival_time']
y = df4['stop_name']

for train in df4['trip_id']:
    plt.plot(x,y)

plt.show()
```

This results in the graph below. See link at top of this post for something closer to what's intended here.

My instinct is that my for loop is off but I don't know how to address it here.
[image: erroneous graph]

Comment: For each id, you need to select the data in your frame with that id: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-do-i-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values

Comment: Can you roughly draw what you expect to see?

Comment: @inquirer, for sure, here's a diagram from the link I posted that I'm expecting to see here. [img]https://i.imgur.com/IujHdx1.png[/img] So each line on the graph should be a train (aka distinct trip_id from df) rather than this connected diagram with lots of horizontal lines